# How do I get around error 403 when installing docker CE on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: apt, package-management

I am trying to install docker CE  on ubuntu 19.04. I am getting an error 403.

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/ubuntu-disco/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 99.86.52.107 443]
E: The repository 'https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-disco InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I am following the documentation at https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#os-requirements

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Error 403 usually means your access is blocked.  Are you behind a strict firewall or restrictive network policy?  If so, you may need to use a proxy or VPN.

Comment: Hi, This is a home network. I am not behind a strict firewall or a proxy server. I can update other packages without a problem.

Comment: when I visit `https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/ubuntu-disco/InRelease` in my browser, I also get 403 forbidden.  I don't think you have added the correct repository.  #4 under heading "Set Up the Repository" lists a different source.  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1172300/edit) your question to include the results of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`, and also include the command that you enter to receive your error -- Also carefully re-read all of the instructions from start to finish to rule out the possibility you missed something (we are all human)

Comment: Hi, I am unable to add the results of cat /etc/apt/sources.list because it has over 10 links that I cannot add  at my current reputation. How do I share its contents? You have however given me a direction to follow so I  will check the instructions once again. I have been trying different things from many places.

Comment: Can you please share the list of commands that you used. I am just following the documentation provided on the website. I am very new to this and I am not sure how to work around the 403 error

Answer (score 1):

you have to change your CDN try 178.22.122.100, 185.51.200.2
[how to change CDN on ubuntu](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-dns-nameservers-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

if 178.22.122.100, 185.51.200.2 dos not work check [here](https://shecan.ir/tutorials/)
or use google cdn...

Answer (score 0):

NMath,
Once again, many thanks for your help. The break through happened thanks to you observing that the repositories that were there in the docker link were not the same as in the output of my apt command. I deleted the repositories I had used and repeated the steps on the docker website. This time, I was successful in adding the docker repositories and installing it. 
I suspect the root cause of my problem was following an older set of instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Change your DNS.
Changed `/etc/resolv.conf` from `8.4.4.8` to `4.2.2.4` and it worked.